# Apache port 80 error

Tags: apache, port

I'm trying to run a WAMP server, but i think Apache is getting port 80 blocked by something.

I did some research and found that in the event viewer it gives the error:

> > > (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80     .

i looked up 0.0.0.0:80 on netstat -ao, which gave a PID of 4. The only problem is, there is nothing with a PID of 4 on my task manager. Does anyone know what might be taking up port 80, or how i might figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Yes, i did deactivate the port from Skype, and it is forwarded correctly. This started happening i think when I installed IIS, but i thought i got rid of it.(yes i did disable it in control panel)

EDIT:

OK, i just changed the port in the config, all is well. Dont' know why i didn't think of that originally.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solving this problem.

1.If you want to run Apache in another port then:Replace in xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf ServerName localhost:80 by ServerName localhost:81 At line 184. After that even it may not work.Then replace

```
 #Listen 0.0.0.0:80
 #Listen [::]:80
 Listen 80
```

by

```
#Listen 0.0.0.0:81
#Listen [::]:81
Listen 81
```

at line 45

2.Your port 80 is being used by the system or Skype. If by Skype then first quit Skype and run Apache. And you can restart Skype.

1. In Windows  “World Wide Publishing" Service is using this port and stopping this service will free the port 80 and you can connect Apache using this port. To stop the service go to the “Task manager –> Services tab”, right click the “World Wide Publishing Service” and stop.
2. If you don't find there then Then go to "Run > services.msc" and again find there and right click the “World Wide Publishing Service” and stop.
3. If you didn't find “World Wide Publishing Service” there then go to
   "Run>>resmon.exe>> Network Tab>>Listening Ports" and see which
   process is using port 80

[image]

And from "Overview>>CPU" just Right click on that process and click "End Process Tree". If that process is system that might be a critical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some case Port 80 is being used by SYSTEM or other services. This like may helps you

http://openguider.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/how-to-solve-port-80-problems-on-windows/